# Laravel 5 named route to controller action

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5

I have a REST Controller which I extended with a new action `verify()`. Now I want to call this action via a named route, but when I open *www.foo.bar/verify* I get an error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 273: 
Method [verify] does not exist.
```

When I call the action `create` instead in the routes.php it works surprisingly..  This is a kind of strange and I have now glue where my error is...

**How can I can I call my verify() action with a name route?**

#### app/Http/routes.php

```php
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::resource( 'activation', 'ActivationController' );
Route::get( 'verify', [ 'as' => 'verify', 'uses' => 'ActivationController@verify' ]); // throws an error
// Route::get( 'verify', [ 'as' => 'verify', 'uses' => 'ActivationController@create' ]); // this works ?!?
```

#### app/Http/Controllers/ActivationController.php

```php
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ActivationController extends Controller {
// ....

public function verfiy(  ) { 
    return "verify";
}

public function create()
{
    return "create";
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the function. :)

```
public function verfiy(  ) { 
                   ^^
```

Comment: Happens to all of us. :)